# Run migrations with code from my class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a class library that will be package as a nuget package later.

Either to use my nuget package, I have a method in a file called Injections.cs in my library that you add in your startup.cs file.

It looks like this:

```
public static class Injections
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddServiceAndRoleSecurity(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISecurityService, SecurityService>();
        services.AddTransient<IDatabaseContextFactory, DatabaseContextFactory>();
        services.AddTransient<ISecurityRepository, SecurityRepository>();

        services.AddDbContext<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(@""",
            x => x.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(DatabaseContext).Assembly.FullName)));

        services.AddMemoryCache();

        return services;
    }
}
```

Thus, If you have a project where you want to use the nuget package, you have to add `services.AddServiceAndRoleSecurity()` in your startup.cs

The poblem I have is that in my Injections.cs, I want to run the migration scripts, if there is any new one. I have stumbled across the following code piece:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder CreateDatabase(this IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
{
    using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseContext>();

        var migrations = db.DatabaseAccessor.GetPendingMigrations();

        if (migrations.Any())
            db.DatabaseAccessor.Migrate();
    }

    return app;
}
```

But you usally find this type of solution to the problem where you have a Startup.cs file, but in my case, I don't have any Startup.cs, since it's a class library.

So, how can I run my migrations from my class library?

Comment: Would you really expect a library to run migrations on your database? I am not sure if I would like to see this behaviour?

Comment: ok, but some other layer calls this class library, right? And this other layer has a Startup.cs, right? so what's the problem? call it from there.

Comment: @Riscie: Why would you not like to see this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

create database migrations in a separate application not in the app where you have the business logic. this migrations app can be run as part of the deployment pipeline when the app is being deployed.

I would not load the startup of the app with things such as database migrations.